# Make Google Protobuf 2.4 and 2.5 live together in a single project

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am developing a project, which have dependencies on 3rd party libraries, that use Google Protobuf both of 2.4.x and 2.5.x versions. Is there a way to make them live together in a single project?

Comment: If you're using Maven to manage dependencies, you might take a look at the shade plugin.

Comment: Yep, but Java will either load 2.4 or 2.5 and it results in conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Are the third-party libraries open source? If so, the best thing to do is rebuild both of them using the latest version of protobufs. Newer protobuf versions (like any good library) are backwards-compatible with code written against older versions. You will have to make sure to regenerate the code generated by `protoc`, if the projects' build systems don't do that automatically.

If they are not open source, and you can't get the vendors to update them, then I think the only thing you can do is load the libraries with separate `ClassLoader`s. That's pretty ugly, obviously.